# Is it possible to use EasyMDE with Laravel Livewire?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I use EasyMDE right now.

I load it up like this:

```
// markdown editor init
    const easyMDE = new EasyMDE({
        toolbar: ['undo', 'redo', 'bold', 'italic', 'strikethrough', 'heading-smaller', 'heading-bigger', '|', 'code', 'quote', 'ordered-list', 'unordered-list', '|', 'link', 'horizontal-rule', '|', 'clean-block'],
        spellChecker: false,
        element: document.getElementById('content')
    });
```

It targets the `textarea` with the id "content" and transforms it to its markdown editor, which works just fine!

But now I have to make it work with livewire(validation and other stuff).

I have another, simple input:text above that with the id "title".

When I add `wire:model="title"` to it and write something in it, livewire updates and removes the markdown editor completely, replacing it with the default `<textarea>`.

This is obviously not working out for me, because I must use the markdown editor (and also validate other fields in the meantime).

Is there something I have to change that I don't know about?

If more info is needed please ask and I'll deliver.

Edit#1: So I figured if I put `wire:ignore` in the div containing the `textarea`, livewire just ignores it which would be fine, but I still need to validate it on the backend (which I can't if it gets ignored).